# Are Items Found by Cutting Grass Random, or Fixed?

Tags: bravely-default-2

In Bravely Default 2, when cutting grass in the overworld or a dungeon, sometimes the player receives an item - sometimes money, sometimes gear, sometimes healing items.  Are these drops fixed, where cutting a particular section of grass always rewards the same item, or are they randomly generated when grass is cut?

Answer (score 1):

The items in the grass are randomized but from my experience each "region" of the world map has a different item pool that you can randomly find items from. Along with each dungeon also having their own item pool list as well. Progressing the game seems to have no effect on what items you'll find outside the starting city.